# Why same works for windows and doesn't work for unix?

Tags: c++, c, winapi, unix

In windows API to create process we have `CreateProcess` function.

Now let's consider we want to create process and run `DIR /X` command. Of course in windows there is not executable `DIR.exe` and we can't just pass it to `CreateProcess`. So what to do?

Solution of this problem is quite simple. We just should pass `cmd /C "DIR /X"` (as second argument) to `CreateProcess`.

Now lets try to do the same (not with `DIR /X`, but with `ls | wc`) in unix.

In unix I'm going to use `fork + execvp` to create new process and execute the command. Why I want my command to be `ls | wc`, because in unix single commands like `ls`, `grep`, `ps` are executables and can be passed to exec alone (i.e. not as argument of `sh`, `bash`, ...).

So here again it seems that we can pass `"ls | wc"` as argument of `sh`. (i.e. we can tokenize `sh -c "ls | wc"` and pass them to `execvp`). But Oooops, this doesn't work!

```
char *arg[] = {"sh", "-c", "\"ls | wc\"", NULL};
execvp(arg[0], arg);
```

So question. How can I resolve this problem?

P.S.
In windows if cygwin is installed `cmd /C "ls | wc"` works.

Comment: Avoid editing your question such that existing answers are wrong like this. It makes for a confusing read after the fact. And certainly don't edit existing answers to match your modified question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of the quotes on the argument to sh:

```
char *arg[] = {"sh", "-c", "ls | wc", NULL};
execvp(arg[0], arg);
```

Comment: No difference. This doesn't help. Also I have tried this variant `char *arg[] = {"sh", "-c", "ls", "|", "wc"};` but result the same.

Answer (score 5):

Your list of arguments must be terminated by a NULL pointer.

```
char *arg[] = {"sh", "-c", "ls | wc", NULL};
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the escaped `\"`, this should work just fine:

```
char *arg[] = {"sh", "-c", "ls | wc", NULL};
```

The `"` are merely for the shell to distinguish which part of the input to "group" into an argument, but you don't need them when making your `execvp` call. The effect of your could would be as if you entered `"ls | wc"` in your shell, including the double quotes (try it, you'll get `ls | wc: command not found`).

Comment: Plus the missing NULL termination, as @Mike Pulaski noted in his answer.

Answer (score 2):

It probably would be easier to use system() in your example.